# How do you pass empty arguments in Cake v1?

Tags: cakebuild

According to the [upgrade](https://cakebuild.net/docs/getting-started/upgrade) document it is no longer possible to `./build.sh arg=` as of v1.0.  Indeed, that produces:

`Error: Expected an option value.`

However it also doesn't work with `arg=''`.  I could leave it off and rely on the default value, but that's hard to do from my Azure DevOps pipelines, which read like `- script: ./build.sh --arg='$(arg1)'` where arg1 is a variable defined elsewhere.

The problem is that the variable `arg1` in my DevOps pipeline is defined externally and may or may not be empty.

The best I can think of is passing in at least a space like `./build.sh --arg='$(arg) '` (note the space at the end) and always checking for `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` and always Trimming, but that seems very hacky.

Is there a cleaner solution to pass a possibly empty variable from the command line?  If not how can I rewrite my Azure DevOps YML to not pass the argument if it is empty?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TL;DR; Use a   (space) instead of `=` if the value can be empty/null.

```
./build.sh --arg '$(arg1)'
```

---

Cake v1.0 supports using a space between the `--argumentName` and the `value` as an alternative for the `=` sign. For example:

```
dotnet cake empty-args.cake --arg1 --arg2
dotnet cake empty-args.cake --arg1 valueA --arg2
dotnet cake empty-args.cake --arg1 --arg2 valueB
dotnet cake empty-args.cake --arg1 valueA --arg2 valueB
```

With a sample Cake script like the below, it will output the following:

```cs
var arg1 = Argument<string>("arg1", null);
var arg2 = Argument<string>("arg2", null);

Information("arg1: {0}", arg1);
Information("arg2: {0}", arg2);
```

```
dotnet cake empty-args.cake --arg1 --arg2
arg1: [NULL]
arg2: [NULL]

dotnet cake empty-args.cake --arg1 --arg2
arg1: [NULL]
arg2: [NULL]

dotnet cake empty-args.cake --arg1 valueA --arg2
arg1: valueA
arg2: [NULL]

dotnet cake empty-args.cake --arg1 --arg2 valueB
arg1: [NULL]
arg2: valueB

dotnet cake empty-args.cake --arg1 valueA --arg2 valueB
arg1: valueA
arg2: valueB
```

Answer (score -1):

One key difference with Cake 1.0 is that it beyond keyvalue arguments (`--key=value`), supports flags (`--flag`), and multiple arguments with the same name (`--key=value1 --key=value2`). Which allows for much more flexibility than before.

As no example script provided, my example will be `emptyarg.cake` looking like below

```cs
var arg = Argument<string>("arg", null);

Information("Arg: {0}", arg ?? "NULL");
```

- `dotnet cake .\emptyarg.cake` will output `Arg: NULL`
- `dotnet cake .\emptyarg.cake --arg` will output `Arg: NULL`
- `dotnet cake .\emptyarg.cake --arg="  "` will output `Arg:`

If you want to treat all the above examples as an argument missing, you could create a reusable helper method.

```cs
public string ArgumentNotNullOrWhiteSpace(string key)
{
    var value = Argument<string>(key, null);
    return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)
        ? null
        : value;
}


var arg = ArgumentNotNullOrWhiteSpace("arg");

Information("Arg: {0}", arg ?? "NULL");
```

Then output of

```sh
dotnet cake .\emptyarg.cake
dotnet cake .\emptyarg.cake --arg
dotnet cake .\emptyarg.cake --arg=hh
dotnet cake .\emptyarg.cake --arg="  "
```

will be

```
Arg: NULL
Arg: NULL
Arg: hh
Arg: NULL
```

and you can use `??` operator if you want some default value i.e.

`var arg = ArgumentNotNullOrWhiteSpace("arg") ?? "default"` and the output will be

```
Arg: default
Arg: default
Arg: hh
Arg: default
```

Comment: Unfortunately none of these options really help me.  In order to solve my problem I need to be able to translate them into an Azure DevOps pipeline statement where a possibly empty variable `arg` is defined elsewhere (e.g. in a variable group). I think I may have asked my original question poorly.